# Extracting properties and attributes for entities

Tags: nlp

I want to extract attributes and their values for name-entities. For example:

Lisa has a pet cat named Whiskers. Whiskers is black with a white spot on her chest. Whiskers also has white paws that look like little white mittens.  Whiskers likes to sleep in the sun on her favorite chair. Whiskers also likes to drink creamy milk.

One possible extraction of attributes for each entity is the following:

List:

- Has -> Whiskers

Wiskers

- Color -> Black
- Likes to -> {Sleep in the sun on Lisa's favorite chair, drink creamy mik}

Answer (score 2):

You could search for phrase structures the correspond to the relationships you want to extract. For example, you could find all the phrases of the form `Noun-phrase verp-phrase noun-phrase` and turn them into subject-predicate-object tuples. The more specific your sentence patterns are, the better this is likely to work. The [pattern](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-search) Python library makes this pretty easy to do.

Comment: Just to add a few informations, you'll have to use a PoS tagger in order to get your text structure. A tool like http://nltk.org/ enables you to do so.